# Remove all previous cart if have same product creator

Tags: commerce

Thanks a lot joshmiller, but I need this rule on before add product to cart react event, not after save commerce order.

I need when user (buyer) klick second button add to cart (for multi order), system check the product creator id first, if the product creator id for the second order clicked is same with previous (where is actually on cart) system cancel the previous clicked order.

With this scenario I want to limit order only from same product creator for one times order. So if buyer want to continue order from different product creator they have to do after first order completed.

Any suggest how to solve this using rule?

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to create a rule that reacts on order creation, searches for existing orders for that user, and cancels those orders.

[image: create a rule that cancels the order]

Next, add the condition to make sure you won't pull all anonymous orders. If you allow anonymous orders, you might have to implement some sort of custom session searching for orders.

[image: Add condition]

Next, add an action that brings in a list of entities (we're going to pull a list of orders based on owner).

[image: fetch entity by property]

Then, select Commerce Orders

[image: commerce orders]

This is what the full action looks like when you've set it up for selecting by order owner's user id:

[image: select orders based on user id]

Next, you want to add a loop based on the orders you've pulled:

[image: add loop on orders list]

Next, you want to add an action inside that loop that changes the status of the orders:

[image: select change the order status]

Finally, set the order status to canceled:

[image: set status to canceled]

Here's an export of the rule:

```
{ "rules_cancel_previous_orders" : {
    "LABEL" : "Cancel previous orders",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "commerce_order", "entity" ],
    "ON" : { "commerce_order_insert" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "data_is" : { "data" : [ "commerce-order:uid" ], "op" : "\u003E", "value" : "0" } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "entity_query" : {
          "USING" : {
            "type" : "commerce_order",
            "property" : "uid",
            "value" : [ "commerce-order:uid" ]
          },
          "PROVIDE" : { "entity_fetched" : { "entity_fetched" : "Fetched entity" } }
        }
      },
      { "LOOP" : {
          "USING" : { "list" : [ "entity-fetched" ] },
          "ITEM" : { "list_item" : "Current list item" },
          "DO" : [
            { "commerce_order_update_status" : { "commerce_order" : [ "commerce_order" ], "order_status" : "canceled" } }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```